# Python Parallel Process Matrix Computation

Tags: python, matrix, parallel-processing

I have extremely large matrix files (2K x 14K pixelated matrix) that need to be processed. The computation is as follows.

A sub-matrix is parsed ( 7 x 7 ) and the eigenvectors and eigenvalues are computed and the sub matrix shifts over and computes again and again until the entire matrix is computed. There are functions that conduct all the calculations but the matrix shift is just a simple for loop.

My question is this: Is there a built in parallel processing function that will allow me to compute this faster while NOT having to re-write my current code? I am skeptical that there is a function out there that inherently "understands" a computation like this.

Any help would or insight into a particular type of built in function or general advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!
Pie

Comment: what is each pixel (rgba, int, float?) in your matrix and how is it stored in file? I think this may actually be solvable using numpy and vectorization (internally uses `fork()`)

Comment: Pixels are floats and the data is stored as a simple excel based matrix